# 5/5 for Curious badge, but Activity page doesn't award me

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, recent-activity

Clearly, I have completed the Curious badge - *Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record*.

[image: 5/5 Curious]

Why haven't I been rewarded the badge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the status of this changed today then it'll be a discrepancy between the script that actually awards the badge - which usually run over UTC night and the code that updates your profile in, more or less, real time.

If you still don't have the badge tomorrow then raise an issue.

Comment: Yep, it's past midnight UTC time and I got my badge.

Answer (score 4):

The profile page can tell that you have achieved all that is required for a badge, therefore shows you the details.

But the badges themselves are awarded on a schedule - in this case the badge has not been awarded **yet**.